# passing json data to a ember router

Tags: json, ember.js

I am trying to pass data to the route through an json file.

**app/templates/dashbord.js**

```
{{line-chart data=model}}
```

**app/routes/dashboard.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

  model() {
    return $.getJSON( "app1.json");
 },
});
```

**public/app1.json**

```
[
  ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
  ['Work', 11],
  ['Eat', 2],
  ['Commute', 2],
  ['Watch TV', 2],
  ['Sleep', 7],
];
```

when i am trying to do like this no output is displaying on browser why?
thanks in advance.

Comment: hard to know without knowing more about your line-chart component. Does the network tab in your browser show the data loading? Does the Ember Inspector show anything helpful for that route? Also, I'm fairly sure that unless you've done some aliasing in your route, jQuery's $ is not in the global namespace and you have to do Ember.$.getJSON. Could be wrong about that though and you'd see an error in your console if that's the case.

Comment: If youre using static data from a file why not just import the file with given data. There's nothing async (no need for ajax)

Comment: Just for now i am trying with static data i have to take the live data and to represent it in the graph. For this charts i have installed the addon    "ember install ember-google-charts" . I have follwed this link   http://sir-dunxalot.github.io/ember-google-charts/chart-types/line

Comment: I have added "this" keyword  to over come the $ error. My network tab is not showing that the data is loading.

Comment: For static data `model() {
    return [
  ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
  ['Work', 11],
  ['Eat', 2],
  ['Commute', 2],
  ['Watch TV', 2],
  ['Sleep', 7],
];
 }` you can try this

Comment: thank you I already tried, and it was working but i want it from the json file because in future i have to work on dynamical data so anyone can help me to render it the data from the  json file....

Comment: try this for dynamic `model() { return Ember.RSVP.resolve(Ember.$.getJSON('app1.json')).then((result) => return result; ); }`

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it for Ember to understood it as a promise. Such as:

```
model(){
   return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      Ember.$.getJSON("app1.json")
         .done(function(json) {
            resolve(json);
         })
         .fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
            reject();
         })
   });
}
```

I didn't test the above code. But I was using it something like this. 
Look at [the documentation from Ember](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/RSVP.Promise.html) and [the documentation from jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/).

One more thing, I wrapped this promise code as a service so that I can use it from the whole application.